# Bootstrap drop-down and button in group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, buttongroup

I would like to have the code below to look like the image with Bootstrap 3.3. When there isn't enough space to display all elements in one line they should form a vertical group where the elements use the whole screen width.

Addition: My combo-boxes may change their size and I want to use the rounded corners from bootstrap at all corners.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da7O9.png)

```
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
  </select>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply consider media query. Here is an example:

```css
div {
 text-align:center;
}
select,
button {
  max-width: 120px;
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (max-width:420px) {
  select,
  button {
    max-width:100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select>
    <option>Opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
  </select>
  <select>
    <option>Opt1</option>
    <option>Opt2</option>
  </select>
  <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: My Problem with this solution is, that in my problem the drop-downs may change their size.

Comment: @floriegl yes and you know the content, right ? so you can adjust the media query

Comment: The content is loaded from a database where I can't control the length of the elements.

Comment: @floriegl ok i see. So if i consider my code .. you want the value of the media query to adjust depending on the content ?

Comment: yes, and another point I may misrepresented my question is that I want to use the bootstrap design (see image) for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div>
    <select class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <option><li><a href="#">Action</a></li></option>
        <option><li><a href="#">Another action</a></li></option>
        <option><li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li></option>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </select>
<button class="btn btn-primary butn">
Button
  </button>
</div>
```

If you want to create a drop down menu using bootstrap, try this code format. The bootstrap snippet for button is also added.

```
  <div>
    <select class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <option><li><a href="#">Action</a></li></option>
        <option><li><a href="#">Another action</a></li></option>
        <option><li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li></option>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </select>
<button class="btn btn-primary butn">
Button
  </button>
</div>
```